# parse.com delete a user account including related objects

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I know that to delete a Parse user, we have to call the "delete" method on the authenticated Parse User object. However, that only deletes the user in the User table, but not all data related to that user in other tables. Is there a way to trigger this automatically or do we have to implement this manually via some code in the "before_save" or "after_save"?

Also, should I log out the user after deleting his account?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in before_save or after_save, but I would go with a hardcoded version of this. It strongly depends on your data structure, but generally, you would have to query for *all the objects related to a user* and then delete them separately (in background).

I would also log out the user, because due to caching, the app often doesn't realise that the user doesn't exist anymore, so I would go for logging the user out from Parse (even if that logout may fail because there is no user to logout anymore) and log him out of the app by showing him the login screen or whatever you're usually doing.

You see, deleting every information related to a user is a quite time and resource expensive task to do, so usually one simply deletes the user and his private information, and leaves the rest (for example in a messenger app, you would not delete the messages, as you want the other users still to be able to see what they wrote to the - now deleted - user).

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought about the messages example. Good call. My question is, what are the benefits of doing this "hardcoded" on the client, and not let the server handle it in the "after_save"? I feel like this could be a "long running" task and would make more sense on the server?